# HTML 5 File System how to increase persistent storage

Tags: html, google-chrome, storage, html5-filesystem

Following this guide: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage#asking_more

When I execute

```
navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, console.log.bind(console));
```

I receive output `10737418240 bytes (10.73GB)`, which is the calculated maximum size when using Temporary storage:

> (available storage space + storage being used by apps) * .5

However, I did press OK to allow allocating more storage than that. So why don't I get the requested storage?

> An application can have a larger quota for persistent storage than
>   temporary storage, but you must request storage using the Quota
>   Management API and the user must grant you permission to use more
>   space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot allocate more than 10GB of HTML5 persistent storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970971/cannot-allocate-more-than-10gb-of-html5-persistent-storage)

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem posted here [Cannot allocate more than 10GB of HTML5 persistent storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970971/cannot-allocate-more-than-10gb-of-html5-persistent-storage/)
Conclusion: maximum persistent storage quota is 10GB, and the documentation saying it's limited by user's free disk space is incorrect.