# Cannot allocate more than 10GB of HTML5 persistent storage

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

When I try to execute

```
navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 15, function (bytes) {
        console.log('Successfuly allocated ' + bytes + ' bytes of persistant storage.');
        }, function (e) {
            console.log('Failed to allocate persistant storage!');
        });
```

then Chrome will allocate only 10737418240 bytes which is exactly 10GB, but I asked for 15GB. Of course, I did click "allow" to allocate more storage. Has anybody met this problem?

EDIT: I don't see any reason why somebody has downvoted my question. 
The reason why I want to allocate that much data, is that our application must store large amount of medical images. 10GB is definitely not enough.
Furthermore, from https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage#persistent:

> Maximum storage space  --   As large as the available space on the hard drive. It has no fixed pool of storage.

EDIT2: NO, my disk is not full. Available space is around ~110GB.

Comment: why would you ever want to store that much. that's an unreasonable amount, I'm surprised it lets you do anywhere near 10GB

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage

Comment: Disk full? I thought the limit for local storage was somewhere around 5MB...

Comment: It's not local storage. Local storage and persistent storage are two completely different types of HTML5 storage.... I have edited my question, explained why we need such large amount of data.

Comment: Are you sure chrome wont actually create more storage as it gets filled? I mean, it seems stupid to reserve a file the size of everything remaining on the hard drive, that would make the computer inoperable. Maybe when you fill up the ten it will slowly expand and then ask for storage permissions again once you hit 15?

Comment: Noo, that's not working like you think... Chrome is not creating a file of requested size. It just has to know, how much data user **may** write to persistent storage. It's not expanding requested storage quota dynamically either...

Comment: Is the disk formatted with FAT32? Can you create a file with size of 4294967294 bytes?

Comment: @DLeh The application at the company I work for is built in a similar way, to work offline, using the Chrome Filesystem API to store around 4GB of data.  The app is used by our sales team to sell timeshares and vacations.  The app contains our resorts and partners data, including images and some videos (not even high res images).  It's built run purely on the local filesystem thus doesn't rely on internet connection (which led to lost sales, in the past).  The performance gains from working with local, offline assets is markedly higher along with reducing bandwidth from constant server calls.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel My disk is formatted with NTFS so it's not the problem.

Comment: Well, seems like a bug to me. Maybe you should file a bug report to Google.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have reported bug to Google. Turns out that max persistent storage quota is indeed 10GB, but documentation saying "As large as the available space on the hard drive" is incorrect.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=540574&q=persistent%20storage&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified