# Google docs offline allocates more than 10GB of HTML5 persistent storage

Tags: html, file, google-docs, offline

When I try to allocate more than 10GB of HTML5 persistent storage using Quota Management API, it restricts the storage limit to 10 GB only.  [Already reported as a Bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970971/cannot-allocate-more-than-10gb-of-html5-persistent-storage)

Google provides the docs offline feature using HTML5 offline storage's that includes file system. I have almost 85GB of free space in C drive.

a) Google docs allocate 85GB as persistent storage. 
[[image attached]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZjs2.png)

b) Before allocating any persistent storage, user have to grant the permission for it. but in case of google docs offline feature, it doesn't ask for any such permission.

I am wondering how this is possible???